# NextJS axios interceptors set/get cookie

Tags: axios, next.js

Using NextJS 12 and axios to try to get and set a cookie in the interceptor on the server side with no luck. Does anyone know how to get/set cookie in this instance?

```
const axiosApiInstance = axios.create({ withCredentials: true });

axiosApiInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  async config => {
    config.headers = {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${config.headers.cookie}`,
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

    config.withCredentials = true;

    return config;
  },
  error => {
    Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

axiosApiInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  response.headers.cookie = cookie.serialize(
    "token",
    "hello world"
  )

  return response;
}, async function(error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Is there someway I can pass the cookie as an argument to the interceptor?

```
const response = await axiosApiInstance.post(cookie??, url, data, { headers: cookie?? }}
```

Comment: did you find any solution?